# How do seperate and print a string every certain amount of characters?

Tags: java, string, loops, substring

write a static method called wordWrap that accepts a String as a parameter, and prints it to the console. 
It is required that each line should have 7characters except that the last line 
can have less than 7 characters.

Create a String “Test the java codes of WordWrap.”. Call wordWrap on the String.

> output
>
> Test th
>   e java
>   codes o
>   f Word
>   rap.

This is the code I have so far.

```
public class WordWrap 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String x = "Test the java codes of WordWrap.";
        wordwrap(x);
    }
    public static void wordwrap(String input1) 
{
    While(input1.length()>7)
    {
        System.out.println(input1.substring(0,8));
        input1 = input1.substring(8,input1.length());
    }
    System.out.println(input1.substring(0,input1.length()));
}
}

/*public static void wordwrap(String input1) 
{
While(input1 > 7);
System.out.println(input1.substring(0, 7));
System.out.println(input1.substring(8, 14));
System.out.println(input1.substring(15, 21));

}
}*/
```

Comment: What is the question/problem with your code?

Comment: If you're supposed to split the string into 7 character chunks, why are you splitting the string into 8 character chunks?

Comment: You do know that `input1.substring(0,input1.length())` is the same as `input1`, right? Substringing from 0 to length returns the entire string. --- And, you know, `input1.substring(8,input1.length())` is the long version of `input1.substring(8)`.

Comment: @m0skit0 My guess would be the compile error caused by writing `While` in mixed case. Or the chunking into 8 character blocks, instead of 7 character blocks.

Comment: Change `While` to `while` (Java is case sensitive) and then change `input1.substring(0,8)` to `input1.substring(0,7)` and lastly `input1.substring(8,input1.length());` to `input1.substring(7,input1.length());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd iterate over the string's length and print substrings of it:

```
String str = "Some string from user input";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 7) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(i, Math.min(str.length(), i + 7));
}
```

Comment: Guiding OP to fix/improve the code in the question is likely a more useful endeavor, especially since the code is 99% there.